# How can I configure my two routers so any device can connect to a server on any other?

Tags: networking, router, nat

Network setup:

- ADSL2+ modem/4-port router (SpeedStream 6520)
- Wi-Fi+3-port router (TD-W8960N, 4th/WAN port connected as device to modem/router)

I have to admit that I know pretty much nothing about networking; I have no idea whether this is really easy to solve or fundamentally unsolvable (which is why I'm asking here - if this is unsolvable make that an answer and I'll accept it).

I want to be able to connect to SSH, VNC, Web servers, etc, on any device on either router, from any other device on either router. In other words I want to be able to see the IP addresses of all my devices regardless of which device I'm using or network I'm on.

Right now I have a few port-forwards configured on the Wi-Fi router so I can VNC or SSH to its IP address and have the connection NATed through, but that only services a single IP and is thus extremely impractical.

I can of course SSH/VNC from any device connected to the Wi-Fi router to any other device on the network, since the devices connected to the Wi-Fi router can see all the IP addresses - this is basically what I want to do for all devices across both routers.

Comment: You write "but that only services a single IP and is thus extremely impractical." <-- that is not true at all. Surely you are aware that one port forward can go to one IP:PORT, another port forward can go to another IP:PORT

Comment: Are you basically trying to daisychain the routers? Easy: 1. Plan your IP ranges for static and DHCP (e.g static 192.168.1.10-99 dhcp 192.168.1.100-254). 2) main router 192.168.1.1 (gateway) 3) give second router a static of .10 4) turn off its dhcp server capability 5) connect it to your lan using I've of its LAN ports - never the WAN. 6) done.

Comment: @barlop: Yes, but if I want to SSH to two or three computers, I'd have to give each one a separate port allocation.

Comment: @i336_ Well, with just NAPT then yes you would need a separate port allocation, but you can do different IP addresses so what you said was not true. And what Chris said won't change that either.. How you assign your IP Addresses doesn't make or break it

Comment: Why don't you correct your question where you write about only being able to service a single IP.

Comment: I meant natively, in hardware, without any software-specific configuration.

Comment: ...UPDATE: So I just learned why my Wi-Fi router seemed to be so flaky - its 4MB flash chip is actually faulty and parts of the filesystem won't read. Whole chunks of the Web UI don't respond at all, and it's a wonder it boots. Telnet works, but I am *not* poking that until I have a new router in case I brick the Wi-Fi on this thing (it's the only AP in the house). Thanks heaps guys!

Comment: @i336_ get one that supports DDWRT as googling about it says something about VPNs

Answer (score 0):

You really should correct your question particularly when I pointed out the error in it, you left it there with the error.

I have actually once implemented what you speak of, in two different ways, with only one port open, VNCing to any computer behind the network.

Method 1-   SSH to the NAT router which forwards to one machine, but specify in the ssh command with -L, which machine to forward to, and then VNC through it.

Method 2- VPN, then VNC to whichever computer

Method 2 is much easier. Look up videos or article on how to do a VPN in Windows [or Linux]. You need one port forward too.

Comment: Neither of the computers is running Windows though (both are Linux); I've been meaning to learn how to setup OpenVPN but I have to admit I wouldn't prefer to use a software stack to solve a problem like this on my local network when I can solve it in hardware. I've actually already used method #1 in the past but I find it extremely clunky to setup - and like a VPN, it's a software system, and significantly less efficient than configuring my hardware do the same thing, considering I have access to it and can make the changes.

Comment: @i336_ I also put off learning how to set up a VPN (though with windows and it turned out to be quite quick in wndows and may be in Linux too with openvpn).u may find that OpenVPN is a lot less clunky than SSH.  I find ssh's syntax laborious.Stunnei may be another option though I haven't used it in quite a while.. that uses a configuration file i'm not sure if it'd do it..If it can be done in hardware,u could direct the q to DDWRT people or Tomato people.that's quite pwoerful router firmware (ur router would have2 be able to run DDWRT or Tomato) for that q to be relevant though

Comment: @i336_ there may be routers with VPN servers built in. Look up about DDWRT and VPN servers.